# RNNLIB Warning Seq, image size, height and width ratio

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

Hi RNNLIB experts and users, 
I am running some data using [RNNLIB](https://sourceforge.net/p/rnnl/wiki/Home/) developed by [Alex Graves](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/) et. al. forked by other developers and getting warnings saying (i.e.) **Warning, seq image1.jpg has requiredTime 25 > totalTime 16**. My understanding is the source of warning is due to image size (height and width ratio) which is relevant to number of time series. Would anybody please have any ideas to share with me or guide me to any useful documentation? I have already checked some of online resources and also seen people asked the same question but no clear solution has been provided so far. Your prompt help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find anything, I have the same problem?

Comment: Actually yes, you need to play with inputBlock in the config file. The value worked best for my data was 1,2. If you take a look at Alex Grave's paper, he explained it a bit. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your response Saman. I am using I AM Online Handwriting database to train, I had changed it to 1, 2 but there were still images which were showing warning. Also did RNNLIB suited for your purpose. I have been searching online for some time now, and didn't find any results from RNNLIB. Did it give good results? If yes I will spend time reading through his thesis where he has explained stuff in detail.

Comment: Actually, it really worked for me but it was difficult to figure out some details as the documentations are not very good.The inputBlock is the only parameter that you need to play with and to get the minimum number of warning. Keep changing that to get the best results. In high-level explanation, this value is used for some kind of implicit character segmentation.